# Install Sublime text editor latest working version

Tags: software-installation, text-editor, sublime-text

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and trying to install **Sublime text editor** latest version.

- I tried to install it by using the `.deb` file but it's asking for a license.
- I also tried to install it by terminal and commands but it says unregistered and not working properly.
- I downloaded the latest build but it also says unregistered.

Here is a screenshot when I try to open a folder using Sublime.

[image: Sublime Text Unregistered]

Comment: It's saying unregistered because it is! You need to buy a license key to get rid of the 'unregistered' text.

Comment: @AvishekSaha is there any free version i can use

Comment: You are using the free version already!

Comment: Sublime Text is free to evaluate for an indefinite time. However, the developer builds of Sublime Text are only for paying customers.